# How can I validate all the mandatory fields in POST request using postman automation

Tags: automation, postman

I want to validate whether all the fields in the request body are mandatory or not using Postman automation
example:

```
{
    "id": "A123",
    "Name": "Ravi",
    "registered": "Yes",
    "address_attributes": {
    "address": "Karnataka",
    "pincode": 123456
  }
}
```

I have a request like this, I want to remove each field at a time and send the request.

first request:

```
{
    "Name": "Ravi",
    "registered": "Yes",
    "address_attributes": {
    "address": "Karnataka",
    "pincode": 123456
  }
}
```

second request:

```
{
    "id": "A123",
    "registered": "Yes",
    "address_attributes": {
    "address": "Karnataka",
    "pincode": 123456
  }
}
```

and follows..
Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like this to the `Pre-request Script`:

```
pm.test("Check request properties", () => {
    let requestData = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw)
    pm.expect(requestData).to.have.keys(['id', 'Name', 'registered', 'address_attributes'])
    pm.expect(_.get(requestData, 'address_attributes')).to.have.keys(['address','pincode'])
})
```

There's probably an easier and cleaner way of doing it though.

Comment: Thanks Danny for the response, But I have 30+ fields in my request body

Comment: Adding the correct details to the question would help here